# find prune not working

Tags: shell

I am trying to find all ruby files in the project. However I want to ignore all the files residing under directory vendor.

```
find . -name .vendor -prune -o -name '*.rb' -print
```

Above command is not working. Anyone knows the fix?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

`find . -name '*.rb' ! -wholename "./vendor/*" -print`

You may have to escape `!` (i.e. write `\!`) character depending on your shell.

Comment: find . -name '*.rb' ! -wholename "./vendor/*"  | ack vendor
works. However find /Users/dorelal/dev/working/demo_app -name '*.rb' ! -wholename "./vendor/*"  | ack vendor is not working. Any idea why?

Comment: not working means even the .rb files under vendor directory are showing up.

Comment: `! -wholename <pattern>` means to exclude every path that matches <pattern>. When you exec `find .` every path starts with `./`. when you exec `find /path/to/sth` every path `find` reports starts with `/path/to/sth`. So you'd need to change pattern to `*/vendor/*` or `/path/to/sth/vendor/*`.